# Want to show the information about execution of methods in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

The button click event of my ASP.NET(2015) application has 5 methods and each is taking long time to complete. I want to show the information about execution of each methods to the user like method1 is completed and method2 is started running like this...

```
protected void Unnamed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl.Text = "Retriving Employee details";
        GetEmplyeeDetails();
        lbl.Text = "Processing Employee details";
        ProcessEmployeDetails();
        lbl.Text = "Generating reports";
        GenerateReports();
        lbl.Text = "Uploading...";
        UploadDetails();
        lbl.Text = "Pushing data to database";
        PushResultToDatabase();

        lbl.Text = "Completed Successfully";
    }

    private void GetEmplyeeDetails()
    {

    }
    private void ProcessEmployeDetails()
    {

    }

    private void GenerateReports()
    {

    }

    private void UploadDetails()
    {

    }

    private void PushResultToDatabase()
    {

    }
```

In my screen, When I click the button, it shows the last message only but  I want to show the information like I have mentioned in the lbl.Text above code

Can anyone please help me to achieve this.

Thanks,
Lenin

Comment: aspnet does not work like that. Only the last change of `lbl` will be send to the client. If you really want something like that you need an ajax solution.

Comment: Please let me know if know how to do this. Thanks